# What causes connection errors resulting in: message from server: "xxxx' is blocked because of many connection errors'

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hikaricp

My application uses Hikari DB Pool. I run the application on one of my local machines (it's home network) but application uses remote database hosted by other company.

The application inserts some records every 5 minutes to the DB so it is in constant use.

Everything works fine, but from time to time (completely undeterministic), the database blocks my IP saying:

> message from server: "Host 'xxx' is blocked because of many connection errors; unblock with 'mysqladmin flush-hosts'

Before that happens - I do not notice any strange behaviour.

So here is my question (**I do not ask how to unblock it!! :)**):

- How can I find an error - is this a problem with my application or maybe it's caused because of remote connection?
- In any case, how to detect and prevent such connection errors before DB will block my IP again?

I use java + spring data + hibernate + hikari db pool.

Comment: It sounds like perhaps too many threads are taking connections from the pool without releasing them.

Comment: how is this related to connection error on DB host side? Furthermore I think, spring handles connection releasing automatically. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Mariusz.v7 That depends on how you are using Spring and database connections. I wouldn't just count on it: make sure it does.